# Merge property from an array of objects into another based on property value lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have 2 arrays of objects, they each have an `id` in common.  I need a property from objects of array 2 added to objects array 1, if they have matching `id`s.

Array 1:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: tom,
        age: 24
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: tim,
        age: 25
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: jack,
        age: 24
    },

]
```

Array 2:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        gender: male,
        eyeColour: blue,
        weight: 150
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        gender: male,
        eyeColour: green,
        weight: 175
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        gender: male,
        eyeColour: hazel,
        weight: 200
    },

]
```

Desired Outcome:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: tom,
        age: 24,
        eyeColour: blue,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: tim,
        age: 25,
        eyeColour: green,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: jack,
        age: 24,
        eyeColour: hazel,
    },

]
```

I tried using lodash `_.merge` function but then I end up with all properties into one array, when I only want `eyeColour` added.

Comment: These are not associative arrays. They are arrays of objects. The term "associative array" is not used in JS.

Comment: Removed that term, any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed Paul answered while I was working on my answer but I'll add my very similar code anyway:

```
var getEyeColour = function (el) { return _.pick(el, 'eyeColour'); }
var out = _.merge(arr1, _.map(arr2, getEyeColour));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/op6xz8aq/1/)

Comment: Am I missing something, or does this solution assume that the order of the elements in the two arrays are the same?

Comment: Yes, and that's a mistake. OP you should probably ignore this.

Answer (score 7):

Lodash remains a highly useful bag of utilities, but with the advent of ES6 some of its use cases are less compelling.

For each object (person) in the first array, find the object in the second array with matching ID (see function `findPerson`). Then merge the two.

```
function update(array1, array2) {
  var findPerson = id => array2.find(person => person.id === id);

  array1.forEach(person => Object.assign(person, findPerson(person.id));
}
```

For non-ES6 environments, rewrite arrow functions using traditional syntax. If  `Array#find` is not available, write your own or use some equivalent. For `Object.assign`, if you prefer use your own equivalent such as `_.extend`.

This will merge all properties from `array2` into `array1`. To only merge `eyeColour`:

```
function update(array1, array2) {
  var findPerson = id => array2.find(person => person.id === id);

  array1.forEach(person => {
    var person2 = findPerson(person.id));
    var {eyeColour} = person2;
    Object.assign(person, {eyeColour});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) to get only the properties you want before merging:

```
var result = _.merge( arr1, _.map( arr2, function( obj ) {
    return _.pick( obj, 'id', 'eyeColour' );
}));
```

Comment: @Andy Thanks for fixing that.

Comment: Not quite sure about this. What is the point of picking `id`? It will overwrite a (possibly different) id in the first array.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascript

This is a more generic solution for merging two arrays which have different properties to union in one object with a common key and some properties to add.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'tom', age: 24 }, { id: 2, name: 'tim', age: 25 }, { id: 3, name: 'jack', age: 24 }, ],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, gender: 'male', eyeColour: 'blue', weight: 150 }, { id: 2, gender: 'male', eyeColour: 'green', weight: 175 }, { id: 3, gender: 'male', eyeColour: 'hazel', weight: 200 }, ];

function merge(a, b, id, keys) {
    var array = [], object = {};

    function m(c) {
        if (!object[c[id]]) {
            object[c[id]] = {};
            object[c[id]][id] = c[id];
            array.push(object[c[id]]);
        }
        keys.forEach(function (k) {
            if (k in c) {
                object[c[id]][k] = c[k];
            }
        });
    }
    a.forEach(m);
    b.forEach(m);
    return array;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merge(array1, array2, 'id', ['name', 'age', 'eyeColour']), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Personal super hero :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, but I want to match Id before merging

And in my case, second array may have different number of items, finally I came with this:

```
var out = arr1.map(x => {
    return  { ...x, eyeColour:  arr2.find(y => x.id === y.id)?.eyeColour }
});
```