# Angular 2 Ionic 2 - Compare two arrays, and get the ID’s from the NAME values that match into a New array.

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, ionic2-select

I have a data entry page that is used to collect data for an HTTP PUT request.  One of the ion-select options provides some name values to choose from.  I need to get the ID’s from that array that match the users selected names for the PUT request; and not sure how to go about doing this.  I found something similar here: [comparing two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965688/comparing-two-arrays-of-objects-and-exclude-the-elements-who-match-values-into), they are trying to find the differences between the arrays in this example.  Also, they are not using Angular/Ionic 2.  Is there a simple way to do this in Angular/Ionic 2 that I’ve overlooked?.. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I think the way you refered above is very simple and no need to find another way. Angular and Ionic do not have any built in function to do it.

Comment: you need to make a function or method to do that. simple filter or map out the indexes. and some conditions will do what you need.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Duannx and Jake.  I'll move forward with this approach.

Comment: I tried something referenced in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)  It works, but the problem is it only returns the same NAME.  I need to get the ID from the "allchoices" array too, which is not included in the "selected" array.  Wondering if there is a way to just add the ID to HTML as a hidden field or something? ..  This is example of what is just returning name: `results = this.selected.filter(e=> this.allchoices.indexOf(e) < 0);`

Comment: **UPDATE**  I tried below, but it returns everything from "allchoices" array which is basically everything.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  `var getID = function (obj) { return _.pick(obj, 'id', 'name'); }
this.results = _.merge(this.selected, _.map(this.allchoices, getID));`

Comment: I tried some additional things referenced here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795049/merge-property-from-an-array-of-objects-into-another-based-on-property-value-lod), but they don't work in Angular/Ionic 2: