# Firebase: Mapping child key from one table to another table

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new to firebase database and I need some help with mapping to two tables.

1. I got two tables, robots and templates. Template key is assign to child node under robots table. [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1ma.png)
2. In robots table, i want to show the template name instead of key. 
   [tables display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhTgq.png)
3. How can I restrict deleting template when it assign to robot.

Here is GET from firebase db.

```
export class Robot {
$key: string;
title: string;
password: string;
otp: number;
roboid: string;
createdtimeStamp: number;
updatedtimeStamp: number;
createduser: string;
status: string;
assignedtemplate: string;}

export class Template {
$key: string;
title: string;
createdtimeStamp: number;
updatedtimeStamp: number;
createduser: string;
messages: string[];}

getRobosList(query?) {
return this.robosRef.snapshotChanges().map(arr => {
  return arr.map(snap => Object.assign(snap.payload.val(), {$key: snap.key}));
});
```

}

Comment: This might have some answers to your question https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: @NoelKriegler I realize the problem is from observable arrays, I am trying to solve with rxjs. Now, I use subscribe from rxjs and can finally print key from my robot table. my code is like this "this.robots.subscribe(res => res.forEach(element) => { console.log(element.assignedtemplate); });". Now I am finding a way to extract title from template using that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem lies on my understanding of rxjs and observable. So, I use shortcut to achieve my objective with the following code.

```
this.templates.subscribe(temp => {
  temp.forEach(item => {
    if ( item.$key === this.myassignedTemplate) {          
      this.selectedRobot.assignedtemplatename = item.title;
    }
  });
  this.rs.updateRobot(this.selectedRobot);
});
```

1. I expand one column to save title
2. subscribe to firebase observable
3. In my subscribe, I loop and compare with myassignedtemplate
4. update from subscribe to firebase.

This is the result. [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSLu6.png)

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795049/merge-property-from-an-array-of-objects-into-another-based-on-property-value-lod) question resemble my issue.

Welcome to improve my answer too.
Thanks everybody.